# Script DB Level Permission Before Refresh to Non Prod Environment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a script that I can use to script out all database level permissions.

- Script users \ permissions
- Restore DB From Prod to Non Prod
- Drop Prod Users and Run script to apply original permissions

There are a lot of scripts out there. But i am unsure which one to use. Would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know if you are going to find something tailor made for your requirements, but it should be straightforward to modify something like sp_helprevlogin to suit your purposes.

Comment: sp_helprevlogin would be for server level permissions ??

Comment: [dbatools module - Export-SqlUser](https://dbatools.io/functions/export-sqluser/)

Comment: You can try SSMS inbuilt [Generate Script Wizard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx). You have option to generate script for permission,roles and almost every database scoped object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obviously try using native SSMS functionality.
To scripts database users and their permissions use 'Generate script' context menu option of the database (right click db - tasks - generate scripts).
to restore database from Production to non-Production, again, use Script the action task and then modify it to suit your specific needs (right-click 'Databases' node - restore database - Script button on the upleft of the General tab).
[image]